# Save and set the "not-maximized" window size?

Tags: java, javafx

As a user is closing a program, I would like to save some information about the primary window, so the next time the user opens the program, the window has the same properties.

This is easy to do for whether the window is maximized:

- **Get:** stage.isMaximized()
- **Set:** stage.setMaximized ( boolean maximized );

This is also easy to do if the window is not maximized:

- **Get:** stage.getX() / stage.getY() / stage.getWidth() / stage.getHeight();
- **Set:** stage.setX() / stage.setY() / stage.setWidth() / stage.setHeight();

However, if the window is maximized, these get functions give us the maximized window's dimensions and locations. If I set those values and the user restores the window to a non-maximized state, the window stays similar to its maximized size, rather than shrinking down as the user expect.

**How can I save the "windowed" stage dimensions and location for a currently maximized window that is being closed, and then restore this information when the program is re-opened**?

Comment: If the window is maximized don't save the dimensions(You could save the dimension to 0,0 and never use them.), just save isMaximized=true and setMaximized to true when loading. If not Maximized set Maximized to false and save the dimensions. When loading use preferredSize() or perferredHeight and preferredWidth().

Comment: That doesn't help. When the window is maximized, we need to get {X,Y,W,H} for the window if it were to be unmaximized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this app to solve your problem.

First, create a text file named `properties.txt`. Second, Add some default values to this text file. Now, save the `Stage`'s properties when the stage closes using `setOnCloseRequest`. Next, if you have a `Button` that closes the stage, save the `Stage`'s properties when the button is pressed using the `Button`'s `onAction` handler. Don't forget to always load these settings when the app starts.

> properties.txt:

```
sceneHeight=300.0
sceneWidth=450.0
fullScreen=false
```

> Main:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication56 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Map<String, String> properties = loadProperties();

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Toggle fullScreen");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                if (properties.get("fullScreen").endsWith("true")) {
                    properties.put("fullScreen", "false");
                    primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
                }
                else {
                    properties.put("fullScreen", "true");
                    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
                }
            }
        });

        Button btnExit = new Button();
        btnExit.setText("Exit");
        btnExit.setOnAction((event) -> {
            properties.put("fullScreen", Boolean.toString(primaryStage.isFullScreen()));
            if (!primaryStage.isFullScreen()) {
                properties.put("sceneHeight", Double.toString(primaryStage.getHeight()));
                properties.put("sceneWidth", Double.toString(primaryStage.getWidth()));
            }

            System.out.println("Closing properties:");
            properties.forEach((key, value)
                    -> System.out.println("\t" + key + ":" + value));
            System.out.println();
            saveProperties(properties);
            primaryStage.close();
        });

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(btn, btnExit);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setBottom(hBox);

        if (properties.get("fullScreen").equals("true")) {
            primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        }
        else {
            primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
        }

        double sceneWidth = Double.parseDouble(properties.get("sceneWidth"));
        double sceneHeight = Double.parseDouble(properties.get("sceneHeight"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest((event) -> {
            properties.put("fullScreen", Boolean.toString(primaryStage.isFullScreen()));
            if (!primaryStage.isFullScreen()) {
                properties.put("sceneHeight", Double.toString(primaryStage.getHeight()));
                properties.put("sceneWidth", Double.toString(primaryStage.getWidth()));
            }

            System.out.println("Closing properties:");
            properties.forEach((key, value)
                    -> System.out.println("\t" + key + ":" + value));
            System.out.println();
            saveProperties(properties);
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Map loadProperties()
    {

        File file = new File("properties.txt");
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap();
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                String[] parts = input.nextLine().split("=");
                properties.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("Loading properties:");
        properties.forEach((key, value)
                -> System.out.println("\t" + key + ":" + value));
        System.out.println();
        return properties;
    }

    public void saveProperties(Map<String, String> properties)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String key : properties.keySet()) {
            stringBuilder.append(key).append("=").append(properties.get(key)).append("\n");
        }

        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("properties.txt"))) {
            bw.write(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication56.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```